# Function that calculates the total number of unique words in a textfile

Tags: python, text-files

I'm using Python 3 and I am trying to write a function that calculates the total number of unique words in a textfile. I wrote some code below but when I run it, for some reason I only get 26 unique words when in reality there should be at least 200. Can anyone spot something wrong with my code?

```
def countUniqueWords():
    words = open('phrases.txt')
    numberofUniqueWords = {}
    for word in words:
         try:
             numberofUniqueWords[word] += 1
         except KeyError:
             numberofUniqueWords[word] = 1
    print(len(numberofUniqueWords))

print(countUniqueWords())
```

Comment: Look at the "words" you are counting and you'll realize you they are single letters.

Comment: Each `word` is a line in the text file. You should split it first `words.split()`.

Comment: I'd like to mention two things: 1. You are not closing your file. Use `.close()` or the `with` keyword. 2. With `print(countUniqueWords())`, you are printing the return value of `countUniqueWords`, but `countUniqueWords` doesn't return anything at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Use a set instead of a dictionary 
2) `words` is just a string, you need to use `.split()` in order to get the words in the string.

```
def countUniqueWords():
    words = open('phrases.txt')
    uniqueWords = set(words.split())
    return len(uniqueWords)

print(countUniqueWords())
```

Comment: Hi! I tried using your code but I keep getting the error 'Python: AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'split''

Comment: Nvm, got it! Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating through the charters in the file not the words. You need to make the file a list of words with `words = open('phrases.txt').read().split()` Also you should make sure to remove any punctuation.